# How to traverse an array from both the sides at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am looking for a technique where we can traverse the array from both sides at the same time while maintaining the time-complexity of O(n). Is it possible? and if yes then exactly how?
I am using Java in my case but you can provide a solution in any language.

Comment: `ptr1 = 0, ptr2 = arr.length-1;` So in your while loop,`ptr1++`,`ptr2--` or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: what have you tried so far? you can iterate over it, using i (of the loop) as index of the first element, and (length() - 1) - i, as index of the second element

Comment: @vivek_23 no real need for a second variable :)

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, true :)

Comment: "we can traverse the array from both sides at the same time while maintaining the time-complexity of O(n)" If you are traversing the array from one end to the other, it's O(n). If you traverse the array from one end to the other and back to the start again, it's O(n). If you traverse first, last, second, penultimate... it's O(n). It's O(n) provided you visit each element in the array at most k times (for some constant k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int[] arr = new int[20];
 int i=0;
 int j=arr.length-1;

 while(j>i){
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
   System.out.println(arr[j]);
   i++;
   j--;
 }
```

This is One way other is using for loop like

```
int[] arr = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length / 2); i++) {
  System.out.println(arr[i]);
  System.out.println(arr[arr.length -1 - i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do it , because of , when you have a array with 100 element how do you get element size of array `array.leneth()`function will try to do incremental counting untill reach end  )

Meaning - You have a array there will be 10 element  (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) , How do you traverse , from `1 to 10` and `10 to 1`

steps 1. traverse `1-10` you have to go element by element until reach end

steps 2. traverse `10-1` you have to know length of  full array - Length meaning is  you have to traverse again `1-10` until reach end -  When you  are thinking about reverse  traversing it should be decrements something

> What is the complexity of `1-10` and `10-1`

Step 1 complexity is o(n)
Step 2 complexity  first you have to traverse to get leneght of array it will be o(n) and again you have to traverse reverse then it will o(n)

> Concussion - unnecessary time will waste

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried using simple for loop.**

```
 var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    
    for (var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--) {
      console.log(arr[i] + ' , ' + arr[j]);
    }

 Output : 
       1 , 10
       2 , 9
       3 , 8
       4 , 7
       5 , 6
```